# MSBuild - Project-specific targets for solution does not work

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-wpp

I have a solution that has multiple projects in it, including a web application. I want MSBuild to execute "WebPublish" target against the web application project and "default target" for all other projects in the solution.

[This MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2015) says that I can do it specifying the command line

```
msbuild SlnFolders.sln /t:NotInSlnfolder:Rebuild;NewFolder\InSolutionFolder:Clean
```

But I never could make it work - MSBuild return an error, something like "NotInSlnFolder:Rebuild" target does not exist. It does not matter what target to specify, Build, Rebuild or Clean - it does not work in any case.

How can I achieve my goal of specifying project-specific targets for a solution?

The MSDN documentation does not work. Or have I missed something?

Comment: After finding answer to my own question, I found the reason why even standard targets didn't work for me. Because my project used DOTS in names

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*NOTE: This workaround is not officially supported by Microsoft, so there is no guarantee that it will work forever.*

---

#### Short Answer

In folder with the SLN file, create the file `before.{YourSolution}.sln.targets`, with the following content: (Replace what in curly brackets to whatever you need.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="{MyCompany_MyProduct_WebApp:WebPublish}">
    <MSBuild
        Condition="'%(ProjectReference.Identity)' == '{$(SolutionDir)MyCompany.MyProduct.WebApp\MyCompany.MyProduct.WebApp.csproj}'"
        Projects="@(ProjectReference)"
        Targets="{WebPublish}"
        BuildInParallel="True"
        ToolsVersion="4.0"
        Properties="BuildingSolutionFile=true; CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents=$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents); SolutionDir=$(SolutionDir); SolutionExt=$(SolutionExt); SolutionFileName=$(SolutionFileName); SolutionName=$(SolutionName); SolutionPath=$(SolutionPath)"
        SkipNonexistentProjects="%(ProjectReference.SkipNonexistentProjects)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

After that you can execute the command line:

```
msbuild {YourSolution}.sln /t:{MyCompany_MyProduct_WebApp:WebPublish}
```

---

#### Long Answer

If you add *environment variable* `MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION`, setting its value to 1, MSBuild will not delete temporary files generated for the solution and projects.

This will allow you to find `{YourSolution}.sln.metaproj` and `{YourSolution}.sln.metaproj.tmp` files generated in the solution folder, which are just standard MSBuild project files.

For *MSBuild 3.5*, the generated file is `{YourSolution}.sln.cache` and is retained regardless of environment variables. Analyzing those files, you will understand low-level details of the process and to see the customization opportunities available.

After executing MSBuild with some project-specific target in the .Metaproj file you will find out that **the list of project-specific targets is hardcoded** and **only standard targets are supported** (Build, Rebuild, Clean, Compile, Publish; note: Publish and WebPublish are not the same). *MSBuild 3.5* only generates Clean, Rebuild and Publish targets as well as *a target with just the project's name that means "Build".*

You also can see that `NotInSlnfolder:Rebuild` is *just a name of an autogenerated target*. In reality MSBuild does not parse it and does not care about project names and location. Also note that the *autogenerated target names specify the project name with solution folders hierarchy* if it's in one, e.g. `SolFolder\SolSubfolder\ProjectName:Publish`.

One more critically important thing you will find: The MSBuild Target Name **does not support dots**. *All dots in project names are replaced with underscores*. For example, for a project named `MyCompany.MyProduct.Components` you will have to specify in the command line:

```
/t:MyCompany_MyProduct_Components:Rebuild
```

That's why even standard project-specific target Build didn't work - my project name contained *dots*.

Analyzing file `{YourSolution}.sln.metaproj.tmp`, you will find out that at runtime it tries to import targets from file named `before.{YourSolution}.sln.targets` and `after.{YourSolution}.sln.targets`, if those files exist. This has a key to the workaround for this MSBuild limitation/bug.

Comment: I used the MSBUILSEMITSOLUTION variable to get to the meta project file.  This helped me to find the names of my targets. <solution folder>\<project name>, then replace all DOTS with underscores.  Once I had that info, I could build individual targets from the solution.

Comment: is there any other documentation on the after.sln.targets and before.sln.targets that anyone has come across?

Comment: you have some specific question?
To get more low level info I just equipped with disassembling tools (.NET Reflector, ILSpy) and started reading internals of MSbuild binaries and standard msbuild *.targets

Comment: no specific question i think.  I am wanting to provide some specific targets to my solution to do various things (copy output to a folder outside of the solution folder), but I like to get an understanding of how things are supposed to work and the docs for msbuild are a bit obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your solution file in text editor and check whether following line is exist or not if not then you can add

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` inside the `<Project>` tag.

Hope this help you.