# Pass msbuild variables to a powershell script during a build in TFS 2013

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I'm calling a powershell script from within an InvokeProcess build activity in TFS 2013.

There are a couple properties called `SolutionName` and `SolutionPath` that I want to pass into the script. In the diagnostic build log, I see the properties and their values, but I'm not sure how to pass them to the script.

I can using things like `$env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER`, but I can't seem to access `SolutionName` or `SolutionPath`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can dump all `env` variables using `ls env:`. You could add this to your script and get a list of all available variables.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. SolutionName and SolutionPath are not in the list.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897030/how-to-get-the-solutionpath-in-a-powershell-post-built-script-for-tfs2013